# Repositioning the image and text on a UIButton

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to improve the performance speed of an application.

Currently, I am creating a UIButton and adding both a UILabel and UIImageView to the button which is probably what is causing the massive speed hit. I know a button has an image view and a title and caption, but I'm at a loss as how to style these correctly

The image view has a RectF(4,4,36,36) and the image is the same size. This position never changes
The label is at RectF(80, 12, 206, 25) and has attributes such as font scaling - again, position doesn't change.

I've tried btn.ImageView.Bounds = new RectangleF(...), but the image doesn't show
I've looked at the attributed text for the title or caption, but there isn't any form of font scaling.

I know I can use the EdgeInset methods to move things around, but the documentation from Apple is not that clear as how I would do what I need to do.

How can this be done?

The button looks like this

[image: UIButton]

Comment: Can you provide a picture showing what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure I'll try and upload one but for now imagine a button that extends the length of the screen and is 56px high. On the left is an image at x = 4, y = 4, with a size of w = h = 36. In the middle is a UILabel (x = 80, y = 12)